# Automapper ignore nested collection properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a simple objects:

```
public class Project : Entity
{
    public uint ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cabin> Cabins { get; set; }
}

public class Cabin : Entity
{
    public IPAddress IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastConnection { get; set; }

    public byte ConnectionStatus { get; set; }
    public byte TechnicalStatus { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

So mapping using auto mapper from one to another with some ignores would look like:

```
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Project, Project>()
               .ForMember(source => source.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(source => source.ProjectId, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(source => source.Cabins, opt => opt.MapFrom(cab => cab.cabins));
        });
```

And it works it maps one project object to another, and ignores id and project id and maps collection.

But on that level, is it possible to set what properties from source.Cabins would be ignored?

For example i want to ignore ConnectionStatus, TechnicalStatus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a configuration mapping for `Cabin` entity and AutoMapper would look at these configurations before mapping Cabin entity.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Cabin, Cabin>()
               .ForMember(source => source.ConnectionStatus, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(source => source.TechnicalStatus, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Or you could use AfterMap event to define a default value for these properties.